# C++ SQLite3 returns an empty query immediately after an update

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

I am having an issue with SQLite 3 version 3.7.14.1 where if I do an update then immediately try to do a query it will return 0 results as if it is not there.

Here is a sample of my log:

```
SQLiteDB::beginTransaction: 0
SQLiteDB::prepareStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::executeStatement -- Executing SQL query:SELECT ... ID LIKE '2' ...
SQLiteDB::executeStatement: 100
SqlHandler::queryEvent -- Bound results.
SqlHandler::retrieveEvents -- Result set has 1 entries
SQLiteDB::releaseStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::prepareStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::executeStatement -- Executing SQL query:UPDATE ... WHERE ID = '2'
SQLiteDB::executeStatement: 101
SQLiteDB::releaseStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::endTransaction: 0

SQLiteDB::beginTransaction: 0
SQLiteDB::prepareStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::executeStatement -- Executing SQL query:SELECT ... ID LIKE '2' ...
SQLiteDB::executeStatement: 100
SqlHandler::queryEvent -- Bound results.
SqlHandler::retrieveEvents -- Result set has 1 entries
SQLiteDB::releaseStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::prepareStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::executeStatement -- Executing SQL query:UPDATE id = '2'
SQLiteDB::executeStatement: 101
SQLiteDB::releaseStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::endTransaction: 0

SQLiteDB::beginTransaction: 0
SQLiteDB::prepareStatement: 0
SQLiteDB::executeStatement -- Executing SQL query:SELECT ... ID LIKE '2' ...
SQLiteDB::executeStatement: 101
SqlHandler::queryEvent -- Nothing found.
SQLiteDB::releaseStatement: 0
Accessor::query -- Unable to perform query. queryEvent failed.
SQLiteDB::endTransaction: 0
```

If I do an update on '3' and select '2' there is no problem, only when I update '2' and select '2' (or UPDATE and SELECT on same record)

All of the updated information is correct, but the select fails unless I place a small sleep or break between the operations (can't run back to back)

I am multithreaded, shared cache, and multiple connections

```
sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);

sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(true);

sqlite3_open("file::memory:?cache=shared", &hDBC_);
```

Thanks in adavance for any help.

Edit:
For the begin and end transactions I am using

```
sqlite3_exec
```

For the prepare statements for Query, Insert, Delete, Update I am using

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2
```

For the execute statements I am using

```
sqlite3_step
```

For the release statements I am using

```
sqlite3_finalize
```

Comment: And what are the SQL commands that you are executing?

Comment: For the begin and end transactions I am using
    sqlite3_exec
For the prepare statements for Query, Insert, Delete, Update I am using
    sqlite3_prepare_v2
For the execute statements I am using
    sqlite3_step
For the release statements I am using
    sqlite3_finalize

Comment: I meant *SQL* commands, not C API calls.

Comment: I am doing a statement like UPDATE table1.Item1 = 2 where table1.ID = 2. Then another process is immediately doing a SELECT * from table1. All rows from table1 return except for the row that was just updated (table1.ID = 2). I don't mind if it is old data, (i.e. what ever table1.Item1 had before changing it), I just want it to return the row.

Comment: Also, the database is not returning SQLITE_LOCKED, BUSY, SHAREDCACHE etc. It just returns all rows except the one currently being written to.

Comment: Thank You for the help everyone. 

The problem was in my query. I have a trigger that updates the a "last_modified" field anytime there is an update on a given record. My query has a where clause that says ... last_modified < current_timestamp. So if there were any updates that occur during the same 1s interval as the query, they were dropped. The issue was  that I did not understand/relalize that the precision on the timestamps were 1s.
 
Once again, thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for the help everyone.

The problem was in my query. I have a trigger that updates the a "last_modified" field anytime there is an update on a given record. My query has a where clause that says ... last_modified < current_timestamp. So if there were any updates that occur during the same 1s interval as the query, they were dropped. The issue was  that I did not understand/relalize that the precision on the timestamps were 1s.

Once again, thank you for all the help